# code igniter sessions print_r

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i just used the code

```
$data = array(

                'USERNAME' => $this->input->post('USERNAME'),
                'is_logged_in' => 1

                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

on my controller and the code

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

On the page where i will be redirected after the login. i am watching this video tutorial, and the output he got was something like

```
[session_id] = >
[ip_address] = >
[user_agent] = >
[last_activity] = >
[user_data] = >
[username_variable] = >
[is_logged_in] = >
```

and i only got the output

```
[__ci_last_regenerate] => 
[USERNAME] => 
[is_logged_in] =>
```

why is it? does it have something to do with the code igniter version? or i have errors or misconfiguration? i am afraid that i'll have future errors if the output are not the same.

Comment: double check with using php $_SESSION. if its same then no issue otherwise CI might have some bug. it happens with me as well

Comment: how do i double check it?

Answer (score 1):

NO!!. its not.

**What you set** to your session **you get back that** only. In your session code you set only `USERNAME` and `is_logged_in`. So this two only output when you print the session.

> If **more elements shows than this then there is an Error on session storing**

---

And one more thing

When you use Codeigniter [**session to store in table**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) you will **get back all above**.

**Saving Session Data to a Database**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: but i only copied the code in the tutorial and we got different output.. :( thats why i am so confused.

Comment: are you using tables ??

Comment: no. its because the tutorial i am watching does not use tables yet. but i already have the tables. because i already watched a lot of tutorials and  i just changed my login codes so that it wont be confusing for me. here is the link to the tutorial that i am watching. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpUqyTRxbds/)

Comment: @kev_m [Check this link](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-session/) only i Can recommended this link only